# wizard cannot be closed due to an active operation

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I installed Eclipse latest version in Ubuntu 16.04. When I press create Java project then I gave project name and clicked finish button, but it is not created. It is still browsing.  When I click the cancel button I am getting this message

> wizard cannot be closed due to an active operation. You must cancel the operation before you close the wizard.

Help to me to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: is it happening every-time? try closing eclipse and try again

Comment: It is happening every time

Comment: Can you check `$workspace/.metadata/.log` and offer the error log?

Answer (score 0):

This same error occurred in my case when I opened the Eclipse Market place to install one of the plugin.

So in my case, following were the issues and solutions that worked:

1. I clicked on the stop button (red square button) when it was fetching some data from internet. So after that, I was being shown that error. So Don't press/Stop anything in middle.
2. My Internet connection was weak. Hence, I needed to wait for a long time so that the things running in the Eclipse's background got downloaded. So wait for some more time.